# Align table in the middle in dompdf

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I need help in dompdf. I have a table that will be exported to PDF using dompdf according to the data user will enter. I need that the table will be automatically aligned in the middle of the page if the use inter few data so that the table height is not fitting the page size.

I know how to render PDF using dompdf but, how to make table to Automatically aligned in the middle of the page size? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All cells of the table set style like this:

```
table th, table td{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```